# Gradle Eclipse task not resolving dependencies from MavenLocal

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have my gradle build script set to resolve a TeraData dependency that I have installed to my local maven repository (this dependency is not available on Maven Central).  The problem is that the eclipse plugin fails to resolve these dependencies when generating the `.classpath` file when I execute `gradle eclipse`.

This is the generated `.classpath`, with the problematic classpath entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="D:/Users/Me/.gradle/this/one/is/good.jar" kind="lib" path="D:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/this/one/is/good.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/dev/workspaces/myworkspace/myproject/unresolved dependency - com.teradata.jdbc terajdbc4 15.10.00.09"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/dev/workspaces/myworkspace/myproject/unresolved dependency - com.teradata.jdbc tdgssconfig 15.10.00.09"/>
</classpath>
```

This is my `gradle.build` script, largely copied directly from artifactory's recommended settings:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://dev.mycompany.com/artifactory/plugins-release'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.3"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    /** Note: teradata must be manually installed to local maven repo. **/
    compile 'com.teradata.jdbc:terajdbc4:15.10.00.09'
    compile 'com.teradata.jdbc:tdgssconfig:15.10.00.09'
}
```

What is causing the TeraData dependencies to not be resolved?  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resolving buildscript dependencies from mavenLocal, but not your project dependencies. Try adding this *after* the buildscript block:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks!